# Why would one use both attr_accessor and attr_accessible on the same field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
attr_accessor :password  
attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_confirmation
```

Comment: you mean why using both `attr_accessor` and `attr_accessible` on `password`, is that what you mean?

Comment: yeah..the purpose of using both over it..

Answer (score 6):

`attr_accessor` defines a property and is part of Ruby. Se more [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000478).

`attr_accessible` makes a property available for mass-assignment and is part of Rails. Se more [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible)

Comment: so whats special with password and not with name attribute??

Comment: You need to add more context for anyone to answer that conclusive. Name may be defined from a database table, a base class or something like that

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are using an authentication library in your Rails project. Password is probably a "virtual attribute" in your Rails model (as in, there's no password column in your database table). You need the password accessor methods to keep the plain text password in an instance variable, and then there's probably a callback method that encrypts/hashes that password when your model is saved in the database probably in a different column.

Comment: I guess thats the exact answer but a bit difficult for me to grasp since i am pretty new to RoR..:P;)

Comment: Read more about `attr_accessor`, `attr_accessible` and ActiveRecord callbacks. Password encryption would go to a `before_save` callback: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 3):

Say that, for example, your DB has a table called `posts`. `posts` has the following fields:
`name`, `encrypted_password`. And you have to following Rails model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_confirmation
end
```

Without the `attr_accessible` it would be possible to set `encrypted_password` through mass assignment. Basically with attr_accessible you specify which attributes may be set through mass assignment (in this case leaving encrypted_password out of the loop.

`attr_accessor` creates accessors on your class for the name/symbol given. Basically what it does for you is:

```
def password= param
  @password = param
end

def password
  @password
end
```

I'm guessing that in your case the attr `password` is used in a before_save/create callback. Doing something with `password` and sets the `encrypted_password`. But I'm only guessing here.

Hope that helps!